# Enabling IPAII protocol disable remote conections. Why?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, configuration, connectivity

I have some servers with IPAII protocol enabled with a certain port:

[image]

I'm using 1433 because a long story. but its working. We can use the default port 1433 AND IPAII ( for PHP developers ) with 1433 too.

But in production, when I changed, the server lost connection.

There's no way to explain this in a easy way.

Why I had no problems on one servers, but on another, it lost connection?

If the question is to abroad, I can get it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you modify any of these settings it's common to lose connections until you restart the instance (and sometimes Browser too if you're using it). We have a policy not to do it without an outage window.

Comment: Thanks cody ! What a bad question. I restarted those 2 servers but not the production one. I will try to do it again. Shame on me.